# Nginx web server not displaying web content. Only showing the Default Nginx Page in my browser

Tags: nginx, web-server, load-balancing

This is the page appears when I call my webpage [image: Error Page]I configured two Nginx web server nodes with a Nignx load balancer.

192.168.0.100 - Nginx loadbalancer
192.168.0.101 - Nginx webserver1
192.168.0.102 - Nginx webserver2

If I call the website through my load balancer then its not working, Only showing the Default Nginx Page in my browser. But each web server is working fine, when i call them individually.
This is my loadbalancer config.Do i need to make any change here..?

```
http {
    upstream website1 {
        server 192.168.0.101;
        server 192.168.0.102;
        }

server {
    listen 80; # Listen on the external interface
    server_name  192.168.0.100;

location / {
        proxy_pass  http://website1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What url are you using to access the upstream servers directly for testing?

Comment: http://192.168.0.100

Comment: Sorry I mean are you just using the IP when testing the webserver directly. You put *But each web server is working fine, when i call them individually* - Are you just using the IP when calling them individually?

Comment: Show configs of other servers

Comment: @Drifter104 I am using the IP, I can also use the host name, I added entry in 'hosts' file in all three machines

Comment: Unreadable. Edit the question

Comment: `server {
listen 80;
server_name  192.168.0.101
location / {
root   /var/www/virtualhosts/mysite3.com;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
location ~ .php$ {
root /var/www/virtualhosts/mysite3.com;
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
}` @AlexeyTen

Comment: Question, not the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the upstream out of `http` block and adding port the the upstream configuration:

```
upstream website1 {
    server 192.168.0.101:80;
    server 192.168.0.102:80;
    }
```

Also, do you have this configuration enabled? Should be in `sites-enabled`, or in some config, which gets `include`d into live configuration.

Comment: upstream is not allowed outside http block